# What will be the zend form decorator for the following code?

Tags: zend-framework, decorator

What should be the decorator to place these two elements side by side. Normally it's rendering the default zend's "dl-dt-dd" structure. I need both of these elements in a same dd with a common single label in the dt.

```
$card_expmonth = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('card_expmonth');
$card_expmonth->setLabel('Card Expiration')
    ->setMultiOptions(array(1=>'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'))
    ->setAttrib('style','width:100px;')
    ->setRequired(true);

$card_expyear = new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect('card_expyear');
$card_expyear->setMultiOptions(array(2011=>'2011','2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020','2021','2022','2023','2024','2025'))
    ->setAttrib('style','width:100px;')
    ->setRequired(true);
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$card_expmonth->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array(array('dd' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'openOnly' => true)),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
    array(array('dl' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dl', 'openOnly' => true))
));

$card_expyear->setDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    array(array('dd' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'closeOnly' => true)),
    array(array('dl' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dl', 'closeOnly' => true))
));
```

Not tested. Tell me if it doesn't work.

Read also http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450

Comment: It will be DijitElement instead of ViewHelper. Thank you for giving me the idea of openOnly and closeOnly.